# How to avoid Sybase 15 IDENTITY gaps in a table?

Tags: field, sybase, identity

I have Sybase Table and a Field (Id) with Numeric datatype. The field is also an IDENTITY field.

Data in the table at times get deleted and all of a sudden the identity Field (Id) gets a big gap. Reading through articles, I come to know it's because of chunks of memory allocation for the identity field that causes this issue and quite common in Sybase.

I need to avoid such large gaps as it is absurd. Any help please?

Comment: Gaps in an IDENTITY field is nothing you should care about. This is normal behavior of any RDBMS. Even without knowing Sybase in detail, I'm quite confident that it will not be buggy in this core concept.

Comment: I cannot fully agree with you. Reason being more of aesthetics on the user interface. User gets to use ID fields as key references for transactions and all of a sudden even during one day gets to see a completely different large ID. It becomes difficult to explain this to them, unless I start generating my own sequential ID which then raises the question - why at all an IDENTITY field.

Comment: Indeed this is rather a question of the database design rules you'd like to follow. In a strict sense, your IDENTIY serving as a key must not carry any meaning implied from the user interface. It serves only as a relational identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the identity gap for a table:

```
sp_chgattribute 'nameOfYouTable', 'identity_gap', 100
```

To see the value of the identity gap for a table:

```
sp_help  nameOfYouTable
```

It is in the 'Result set 9', column: identity_gap

Comment: Rob Vershoor also has excellent documentation on this at http://www.sypron.nl/idgaps.html